# Which table stores info about hook_update_N?

Tags: 8, updating

I want to re run same hook_update again. For example hook_update_8005. I am not sure where Drupal put info to track.

Answer (score 7):

The schema version for the update hook is stored in the `key_value` table.

You can set it with the global function `drupal_set_installed_schema_version($module, $version)`.

For example:

```
drupal_set_installed_schema_version('my_module', 8005);
```

If you want the check the schema version number:

```
$schema_version = drupal_get_installed_schema_version('my_module');
```

Comment: You can use the command line to do this: `drush eval "echo drupal_get_installed_schema_version('my_module');"`

Answer (score 5):

To find the row in the *key_value* table where the *value* (value column) is stored for the number in *hook_update_N*, look for the *module machine name* in the *name* column.

For example to get the `N` value for the *block* module, you would run:

```
SELECT value FROM key_value WHERE collection="system.schema" AND name = 'block';
```

Result on a Drupal 8.6 instance is value: `s:4:"8003";`